# OpenCV, C++: Distance between two points

Tags: c++, opencv, mathematical-optimization

For a group project, we are attempting to make a game, where functions are executed whenever a player forms a set of specific hand gestures in front of a camera. To process the images, we are using Open-CV 2.3.

During the image-processing we are trying to find the length between two points.
We already know this can be done very easily with Pythagoras law, though it is known that Pythagoras law requires much computer power, and we wish to do this as low-resource as possible.

We wish to know if there exist any build-in function within Open-CV or standard library for C++, which can handle low-resource calculations of the distance between two points.
We have the coordinates for the points, which are in pixel values (Of course).

Extra info:
Previous experience have taught us, that OpenCV and other libraries are heavily optimized. As an example, we attempted to change the RGB values of the live image feed from the camera with a for loop, going through each pixel. This provided with a low frame-rate output. Instead we decided to use an Open-CV build-in function instead, which instead gave us a high frame-rate output.

Comment: Premature optimization? If you don't really need an exact distance, but just some sort of distance measure, you might do without the square root. But make sure that it's that function which causes you performance problems.

Comment: Do you need the distance or the square distance is fine? The most expensive part of Pythagoras Law is calculating the square root, if you can make do without it you should be fine with a couple multiplications.

Comment: Sadly we can't just skip the root. If it is any help, we are trying to calculate the distance between a line, which reaches from two convex hull points, and a defect point. The reason we can't use an approximated expression like that, is because when the object we are calculating on is rotated, the propositions are changed, changing the approximated result.
I'll attempt to create an illustration of the issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the illustration, but if the lengths of the two dotted lines are the same (that is, the distance between the two points is the same in either situation) then the absence of a square root does not make a difference. Rotation of the situation does not change that.

Comment: What I am attempting to show with the illustration is that rotation does matter, and do output different results when using either euclidian (with square root and 'to the power of'), the dotted line, or a simple length approximation, dist =|x_a - x_b| + |y_a - y_b|.

Comment: No, what we're talking about is this: instead of `length = sqrt((x_a - x_b)^2 + (y_a - y_b)^2)` you can leave out the square root, obtaining `squared_length = (x_a - x_b)^2 + (y_a - y_b)^2`, should you not need the precise length. Rotation does not affect this at all. But I still feel that all of this is premature optimization anyway.

Comment: Please use another image host which does not have expiring storage in the future. The current Imageshack-linked image is not available.

Comment: I am trying to get the distance between two color dots (red and green) and once they are almost overlapping or has distance less than 0.1mm i need to capture the image. I am using norm function(cv::norm(cv::Point(rposX, rposY)-cv::Point(bposX, bposY));) but the value that it returns is in 100s even when the dots are very near. How can i convert the norm returned value into mm or any other unit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, there's an OpenCV function that does some of your work :)

(Also check **the other way**)

It is called [magnitude()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude) and it calculates the distance for you. And if you have a vector of more than 4 vectors to calculate distances, it will use SSE (i think) to make it faster.

Now, the problem is that it only calculate the square of the powers, and you have to do by hand differences. (check the documentation). But if you do them also using OpenCV functions it  should be fast.

```
Mat pts1(nPts, 1, CV_8UC2), pts2(nPts, 1, CV_8UC2);
// populate them
Mat diffPts = pts1-pts2;
Mat ptsx, ptsy;
// split your points in x and y vectors. maybe separate them from start
Mat dist;
magnitude(ptsx, ptsy, dist); // voila!
```

**The other way** is to use a very fast sqrt:

```
// 15 times faster than the classical float sqrt. 
// Reasonably accurate up to root(32500)
// Source: http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/SUPPORT/000419/AN-G-002.pdf

unsigned int root(unsigned int x){
    unsigned int a,b;
    b     = x;
    a = x = 0x3f;
    x     = b/x;
    a = x = (x+a)>>1;
    x     = b/x;
    a = x = (x+a)>>1;
    x     = b/x;
    x     = (x+a)>>1;
    return(x);  
}
```

Comment: This seems like something we are looking for, though I have two questions (I am currently not sitting with my group, and I am actually not the one sitting with the Image-Processing program).
Isn't 'Mat' a part of the older OpenCV syntax? 2.0 or something?
Also, the fast square root seems like a great solution! We might stick to that if we can't get 'Magnitude();' to work.

Comment: i didn't know of the distance, however here's another function that can give the distance (just mentioning it to bounce off the idea). the `cvInitLineIterator()` returns the number of pixels on a line joining two points. However it stores the pixels encountered on the line too - which was why we used it. The length was a 'side-effect'.   http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/drawing_functions.html#initlineiterator

Comment: Mat is the new way to do things. CvMat and IplImage are part of the C syntax

Comment: Your answer with the fast sqrt seems reasonable, though it can't measure integer values under 100. We are talking about a difference in 5 interger values from the normal sqrt(); and root(); until you need to compute values 100+.

Comment: The sqrt approx is just an approx. You must make sure it fits your needs. The link in the comments contain a detailed description and an accuracy diagram of the algorithm.

Comment: Java guys remember to use java.lang.Math instead of implementing power or square root by yourselves

Answer (score 46):

You should try this

```
cv::Point a(1, 3);
cv::Point b(5, 6);
double res = cv::norm(a-b);//Euclidian distance
```

Comment: I am trying to get the distance between two color dots (red and green) and once they are almost overlapping or has distance less than 0.1mm i need to capture the image. I am using norm function(cv::norm(cv::Point(rposX, rposY)-cv::Point(bposX, bposY));) but the value that it returns is in 100s even when the dots are very near. How can i convert the norm returned value into mm or any other unit?

Answer (score 4):

This ought to a comment, but I haven't enough rep (50?) |-( so I post it as an answer.

What the guys are trying to tell you in the comments of your questions is that if it's only about **comparing** distances, then you can simply use
d=(dx*dx+dy*dy) = (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2)
thus avoiding the square root. But you can't of course skip the square elevation.

Comment: The main issue is, we are going to have a lot of defects and a lot of comparisons. If the values we are going to compare have to much offset, we will either get a wrongly output or we would need to spend a lot of time optimizing our comparison algorithm to match the varying offset.

Answer (score 1):

Pythagoras is the fastest way, and it really isn't as expensive as you think. It used to be, because of the square-root. But modern processors can usually do this within a few cycles.

If you really need speed, use OpenCL on the graphics card for image processing.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't consume that much of resources, though it is the first time we are working with image-processing, plus we are trying to have a game running along side with it.
The final resource consumption is unknown to us, so we are trying to be on the safe side.

OpenCL could be a solution, though we don't have the necessary time to explore it :)