# How can i get angle and line length in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, math, geometry

I have a chunk of code to get start, end, far variable from Convexity Defects :

```
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
        defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

        for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
            s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
            start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
            end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
            far = tuple(cnt[f][0])

            cv2.line(res,far,end,[0,255,0],2)
            cv2.line(res,start,far,[0,255,0],2)
```

I need to dismiss a convexity defect from the finger  if:

line_length<0.4lbb and angle>80o

So How can i get angle and line length value from those start, end, far variable? and dismissed convexity defect from given rule?

**Edit**

Is it true that if I use this code, I'll get the angle from my given code?

```
angle = int(math.atan((start[0]-start[1])/(end[0]-end[1]))*180/math.pi)
```

Comment: For angle go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888180/calculating-the-angle-between-points), for length you can see something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269605/opencv-c-distance-between-two-points)

Comment: thanks mate, now i need to configure for angle in pythonic way.

Comment: You mean this `angle = int(math.atan((y1-y2)/(x2-x1))*180/math.pi)`

Comment: I could mean this. Let me try...

Comment: Could you explain where i place variable y1,y2,x1,x2 for given code i've provide? I need comparison for what I think mate.

Comment: Sorry @Gunslinger I think I gave you wrong equation just use atan2(y,x)

Comment: Just use this equation `angle = int(math.atan2((start[1]-end[1]),(start[0]-end[0]))*180/math.pi)` I think it will work.

Comment: Oh thanks, really thanks it works!! I wish I could upvote 10 more your comment!! :D