# OpenCV euclidean distance between two vectors

Tags: opencv, vector, matrix, euclidean-distance

I want to calculate the euclidean distance between two vectors (or two Matrx rows, doesn't matter). Is there a good function for that in OpenCV?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[yes.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm)

```
Mat a,b; // num of rows/cols/channels does not matter, they just have to be equal for both

double dist = norm(a,b,NORM_L2);
```

Comment: And the two matrices necessarily need to have one row only? Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Same for python :

```
    dist = cv2.norm(pts - dst, cv2.NORM_L2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: [OpenCV, C++: Distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269605/opencv-c-distance-between-two-points)

```
Mat pts1(nPts, 1, CV_8UC2), pts2(nPts, 1, CV_8UC2);
// populate them
Mat diffPts = pts1-pts2;
Mat ptsx, ptsy;
// split your points in x and y vectors. maybe separate them from start
Mat dist;
magnitude(ptsx, ptsy, dist); // voila!
```

Comment: Why do you need `diffPts` variable?

Comment: @Sherzod. This answer was a long time ago that I do not remember exactly. However, what I can see from the code is, after you compute diffPts, you can extract the x part into  ptsx and the y part into ptsy. Finally, you can use the magnitude function